# Loop through and Merge Querysets

Tags: python, django

I am sure this one is straight forward but I cannot seem to get my head around it.

I have "Users" who can post "Posts" on my site.

Each user can follow other users.

The idea is to display all the posts posted by the users that current user is following.

Example : Foo followed Bar and Baz. I need to retrieve all the posts from Bar and Baz.

```
Bar = Post.objects.filter(user=3)
Baz = Post.objects.filter(user=4)
totalpost= list(chain(Bar, Baz))
print(totalpost)
```

On this occasion, when both variables userXposts and temp are hardcoded, I can easily retrieve ONE list of QuerySets neeatly by chaining both QuerySets.

However, I cannot have those hardcoded. As such, I am attempted to loop through each user posts and add it in a list since my user can follow X amount of users :

```
QuerySet = Profile.objects.filter(follower=1)

for x in QuerySet:
    userXposts = Post.objects.filter(user=x.user.id)
    temp = userXposts
    totalpost= list(chain(userXposts, temp))
    temp = []
print("Totalpost after union of userpost and temp: ", totalpost)
```

Here, `Profile.objects.filter(follower=1)` return two sets of QuerySets, one for Baz and one for Bar.

The problem that I have so far is that totalpost endup being a "list of list" (I believe) which forces me to call totalpost[0] for Bar posts and totalpost[1] for Baz posts.

Since I am attempting to use Pagination with Django, I am forced to pass ONE Variable only in  `p= Paginator(totalpost, 200)`

Would you be able to assist in the loop so that I can fetch the data for the first user, add it to a variable, then go to the second user and ADD the second QuerySet data to the list where the First User data is?

Thanks a lot !

EDIT :

Here are the Models :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="following_name")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="follower_name")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'"{self.user.username}" is followed by {self.follower.all()} and follows {self.following.all()}'

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=350, null=True, blank=True)
    like = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="like_amount")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'#{self.id}: "{self.user.username}" posted "{self.post}" on "{self.timestamp}". Like : "{self.like.all()}" '
```

Comment: can you give us the models?

Comment: See added models

Comment: You can do it like this `Post.objects.filter(user__ following_name__id=1)`

Comment: You are a genius... thank you for the wizardry !

Comment: see Python [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

Post.objects.filter(user__ following_name__id=1)